# MongoDB 2Gb limit - can't compact database

Tags: mongodb

I have been adding files to GridFS in my 32bit Mongo database.  It eventually failed when the size of all Mongo files hit 2Gb.  So, I then deleted the files in GridFS.  I've tried running the repairDatabase() command, but it fails, saying "mongo requires 64bit for larger datasets".  I get the same error trying to run the compact command against GridFS.

So, I've hit the 2Gb limit, but it won't let me compact or repair because it doesn't have space.  Talk about Catch22!!

What do I do?

**Edit**
This is an immediate problem I have - how do I compact the database right now?

Comment: Switch to a 64-bit OS. The memory limit is to do with addressing and cannot be bypassed due to hardware and software limitations. Besides, why on earth are you still on 32-bit in this day and age?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on my database and I solved it such way. At first I created Amazon EC2 64-bit instance and moved database files from 32-bit instance via plain copy. Then I made all needed cleanups in database on 64-bit instance and made dump with mongodump. This dump I moved back to 32-bit instance and restored database from it. 
If you need to restore database with same name, that you had before, you can just rename your old db-files in dbpath (files have database name in their name)
And of course, you should move to upgrade to 64-bit later. MongoDB on 32-bit OS is very bad in support.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only recourse is to upgrade to a 64-bit OS.

Comment: I agree, but how do I deal with my current, immediate problem?

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Your current, immediate problem's solution is to upgrade your db machine to a 64bit OS. I don't know your infrastructure, so I can't say anymore than that.

Answer (score 0):

shot in the dark here... you could try opening a slave off the master (in 64 bit) and see if you can force a replication over to the slave, essentially backing up your data.  I have no idea if this would actually work, as it's pretty clear that 32bit has a 2gig limit (all their docs warn about this :( ), but thought I'd at least post a somewhat potentially creative solution..